# Extract object into Solr

Tags: c#, .net, solrnet

We need to extract and store C# objects into Apache Solr but weren't sure if anyone has done work on this. Here's an example:

- A Word document being indexed can have a Persons list associated with it.
- Each Person object in the list has these fields,

  - Name
  - Age
  - Email address
  - Phone

How do you store this in Solr? Any .NET examples out there? The only code I could find was the Solrizer, which is Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Solrnet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) library that can help you.

Comment: There are examples of using SolrNet at http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/ I would also recommend you look at the SampleApp in the SolrNet Source - http://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/tree/master/SampleSolrApp